# Error monitoring VM migration using libvirt and qemu

Tags: python, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'm implementing a live migration management tool using libvirt, qemu and python. In my original setup, which includes two Debian boxes I can migrate and monitor the migration without any issues, however, in my production setup, which uses CentOS 6.4 I had to recompile both qemu and libvirt to newer versions in order to support compressed migration. The issue is that even if the migration seems to work right, the monitoring returns an error with:

```
libvirt: XML-RPC error : Too many job stats '19' for limit '16'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./migrate_monitor_migration.py", line 27, in <module>
    remaining = vm.vm_status()
  File "/software/test/VMMigration.py", line 70, in vm_status
    return self.__update_migration_status()
  File "/software/test/VMMigration.py", line 40, in __update_migration_status
    dictionary = self.vm_job_stats()
  File "/software/test/VMMigration.py", line 37, in vm_job_stats
     return self.local_dom.jobStats()
  File "/usr/local/libvirt/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 2045, in  jobStats
    if ret is None: raise libvirtError ('virDomainGetJobStats() failed', dom=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: Too many job stats '19' for limit '16'
```

As it can be observed the error is raised when accessing the jobStats function of the domain.

The strange issue is that while there is no migration in progress the monitoring correctly accesses the monitoring.

To complement the information I'm attaching part of the libvirtd.log:

```
2013-09-22 07:02:22.806+0000: 2652: error : qemuMonitorIO:616 : internal error: End of file from monitor
2013-09-22 07:05:34.120+0000: 2654: warning : qemuOpenVhostNet:495 : Unable to open vhost-net. Opened so far 0, requested 1
2013-09-22 07:05:34.120+0000: 2654: warning : qemuDomainObjTaint:1558 : Domain id=11 name='TESTVM' uuid=348ba295-7665-b7f2-020c-04303c5896a1 is tainted: high-privileges
2013-09-22 07:05:34.154+0000: 2654: error : virDBusCallMethod:1156 : The name org.freedesktop.machine1 was not provided by any .service files
2013-09-22 07:06:16.177+0000: 2655: warning : qemuMigrationCancelDriveMirror:1383 : Unable to stop block job on drive-virtio-disk0
2013-09-22 07:10:41.637+0000: 2653: warning : qemuMigrationCancelDriveMirror:1383 : Unable to stop block job on drive-virtio-disk0
2013-09-22 07:12:00.657+0000: 2657: warning : qemuMigrationCancelDriveMirror:1383 : Unable to stop block job on drive-virtio-disk0
```

Thanks in advance for any pointer.

Comment: it fails to call `virDomainGetJobStats()` which means your Domain is not active. check domain logs under `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/<domain-name>/*.log`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. However this doesn't seem to be the cause, as the domain is active, in the VM log, the only entry refers to the kvm command executed plus: Domain id=11 is tainted: high-privileges

char device redirected to /dev/pts/1 (label charserial0)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue is solved now by downgrading to libvirt 1.1.0 and reinstalling everything.